# 500 - An error has occurred in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

```
500 - An error has occurred.
Layout g not found
```

`Login` Able to working fine, as i came to update the `menu items`, its starts showing this kind of `error` ?
Any help. what does it mean and why its coming in `com_menus` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its only `Chrome` Browser Issues, once you will check it on different `browsers`, it works fine. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browsers cookies :)